# Unidentified Fish-like Microorganism from pond water

Tags: microbiology

I was looking at my friends pond water and saw several Daphnia. As I was searching, I noticed a Pliomate Rotifer and some other unidentified Microorganism. It looked almost like a micro fish, with a strange **patterned disk** around its body
[image: fishlike microorganism, 40x]

That was under 40x magnification there's another image but with the disk hidden from view.
[image: fishlike microorganism, 400x]

That photo at 400x or 800x. I did notice some *fast moving area* near the head almost like cilia, however they were inside and didn't appear to be cilia wiggling. If anybody has seen this type of microorganism before, please do let me know! I'm not sure if it is uni or multicellular given it's size but I'd guess it's **multicellular** given the tail appendage and **complex internals**.